# JSON and CURL problems

Tags: php, json, api, curl

world! I'm having some troubles with my API script with OLX. Can someone help me, please?

I'm making a JSON that returns this:

```
{
 "access_token": "7b1cb35b4eca28be89174d75baf66e00d2728bf6",
     "ad_list": [ 
        { 
           "id": "31dasa1d23", 
           "operation": "insert", 
           "category": 1040, 
           "subject": "Título teste - Anúncio OLX - Marília/SP", 
           "body": "Imóvel com Sala, Copa, Cozinha planejada e Gabinete, 3 Dormitórios sendo 1 suíte, Lavanderia com Área de Serviço Coberta, Espaço Gourmet com Churrasqueira e Chuveirão para Ducha, Garagem para 2 Carros, Cerca Elétrica e Interfone. Confira mais sobre o imóvel: http://www.silvioimoveis.com.br/imovel-residencial-professor-antonio-da-silva-penteado-marilia-sp-venda/principal/imovel/principal/5394", 
           "phone": 1433333333, 
           "type": "s", 
           "price": 260000, 
           "zipcode": "17504000", 
           "params":{ 
                "rooms": "3", 
                "garage_spaces": "2" 
           }, 
           "images": [           
                "http://homologacao.silvioimoveis.com.br/fotos/imoveis_internos/5394/2175ea284f81f03.jpg",                                 
                "http://homologacao.silvioimoveis.com.br/fotos/imoveis_internos/5394/bb0ff30ac2bcbae.jpg"
           ] 
        }
      ]
}
```

And my code to create this JSON is:

```
$json = '{
        "access_token": "'.$data['access_token'].'",
        "ad_list": [
                {
                    "id": "'.$jsonGerado[0]['id'].'",
                    "operation": "'.$jsonGerado[0]['operation'].'",
                    "category": '.$jsonGerado[0]['category'].',
                    "subject": "'.$jsonGerado[0]['subject'].'",
                    "body": "'.$jsonGerado[0]['body'].'",
                    "phone": '.$jsonGerado[0]['phone'].',
                    "type": "'.$jsonGerado[0]['type'].'",
                    "price": '.$jsonGerado[0]['price'].',
                    "zipcode": "'.$jsonGerado[0]['zipcode'].'",
                    "params": {
                        "rooms": "'.$jsonGerado[0]['params']['rooms'].'",
                        "garage_spaces": "'.$jsonGerado[0]['params']['garage_spaces'].'"
                    },
                    "images": [
                        '.$jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkFotoPrincipal'].',
                        '.$jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][0].',
                        '.$jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][1].',
                        '.$jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][2].',
                        '.$jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][3].',
                        '.$jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][4].',
                        '.$jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][5].',
                        '.$jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][6].',
                        '.$jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][7].',
                        '.$jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][8].',
                        '.$jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][9].'
                    ]
                }
        ]
    }';
```

The CURL code is:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://apps.olx.com.br/autoupload/import",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json
));
```

And finally, the error is:

**When I don't use json_encode() in $json variable, I got "NULL value found..." instead of "string value found"**

[image]

Comment: Dont build JSON Strings manually, you will almost definitely make mistakes. Make a PHP data structure and then `json_encode($it);` For a start it has to be UTF-8 encoded, and if you have not got everything _Just Right_ in your script file i.e. the script file must be encoded in UTF-8 etc, it wont be!

Comment: In this case, I would make a json_encode($json)? its my first work with JSON and CURL, so I don't understand too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As RiggsFolly mentioned, use `json_encode` on a PHP array or object rather than building the JSON yourself. Here's an example of how you might do that with the example code you provided:

```
$json_array = array(
        "access_token" => $data['access_token'],
        "ad_list" => array(
                array(
                        "id" => $jsonGerado[0]['id'],
                        "operation" => $jsonGerado[0]['operation'],
                        "category" => $jsonGerado[0]['category'],
                        "subject" => $jsonGerado[0]['subject'],
                        "body" => $jsonGerado[0]['body'],
                        "phone" => $jsonGerado[0]['phone'],
                        "type" => $jsonGerado[0]['type'],
                        "price" => $jsonGerado[0]['price'],
                        "zipcode" => $jsonGerado[0]['zipcode'],
                        "params" => array(
                                "rooms" => $jsonGerado[0]['params']['rooms'],
                                "garage_spaces" => $jsonGerado[0]['params']['garage_spaces']
                        ),
                        "images" => array(
                                $jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkFotoPrincipal'],
                                $jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][0],
                                $jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][1],
                                $jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][2],
                                $jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][3],
                                $jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][4],
                                $jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][5],
                                $jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][6],
                                $jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][7],
                                $jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][8],
                                $jsonGerado[0]['images']['linkDemaisFotos'][9]
                        )
                )
        )
);
```

You can then do `$json = json_encode($json_array);`. I hope that helps!

Comment: Well that saved me a lot of time and hassle, so you get my UV

Comment: Almost there... That code returns: {"access_token":"7b1cb35b4eca28be89174d75baf66e00d2728bf6","ad_list":{"id":"ab013ca67cf2d50"..}}}. I need the [ ] after "ad_list": and the error now is [{"property":"ad_list","message":"object value found, but an array is required"}] ... I need something like this: {"access_token":"7b1cb35b4eca28be89174d75baf66e00d2728bf6","‌​ad_list": **[** {"id":"ab01‌​3ca67cf2d50"..}} **]** }

Comment: Ah, missed that! Made an edit, give the updated code a try.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm still getting some errors, but this part is solved! You saved my day.